# Dot notation in the form of obj.x.y.z

Tags: python

I am trying to learn python and in many codes i see the many codes of the form

```
obj.x.y
```

I know that 
    obj.x
accesses the method x of the object obj , but I can't understand the mentioned form , I need a simple example to understand it. Thanks

I have done my searches but with no result to understand it.

Comment: Everything (just about) in Python is an object, so even if x is a method of obj, obj.x is also an object, so you can use ".y" to access the "y" property of the "obj.x" property. A specific example would be   `  "Hello World".lower().capitalize()  `

Comment: Thanks for the help guys

Comment: `dog.eye.color = brown` & `dog.tail.wag()` are good examples. `x` is part of `obj`, `y` is part of `x`.

Answer (score 1):

`obj.x.y` simply accesses the `y` attribute of the `x` attribute of `obj`

```
class O1:
    def __init__(self, some_object):
        self.y = some_object

class O2:
    def __init__(self, some_object):
        self.x = some_object

o1 = O1('foo')
o2 = O2(o1)

print(o2.x.y)
```

prints

```
foo
```

Answer (score 0):

`obj.x.y` means we are accessing the `y` attribute or function of `obj.x`. `obj.x` might be a class, some instance of a class or any other variable.